# If $x,y \gt 0$ and $x^2y^3=100$ then find the minimum value of $4x+9y$

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $x,y \in \mathbb R$ are two positive numbers.  Is it possible to find the minimum of $4x+9y$?  If yes, how?

Note 1 :  The understanding of question is so easy but the problem is that i don't know any systematic way of answering it. I started to assign a value to $x$ & $y$ but that's not a good idea.

Note 2 : Any beautiful answer is good, but i'd like to see that how can we find the minimum value of a function when we have a predicate like here? I mean, General answers may be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using AM-GM Inequality we have:

$$\frac{2x + 2x + 3y + 3y + 3y}{5} \ge \sqrt[5]{108x^2y^3} \implies 4x+9y \ge 5\sqrt[5]{10800} \approx 32.0372$$

Therefore the minimum value of ${4x+9y}$ is $5\sqrt[5]{10800} \approx 32.0372$

The minimum value is obtained when $x=\frac{3y}{2}$, which when we substitute into the condition yields $y=\sqrt[5]{\frac{400}{9}} \approx 2.1358$ and $x= \frac{3}{2}\sqrt[5]{\frac{400}{9}} \approx 3.2037$

Comment: Your method is right :) thank you :) but i think you meant $2x+2x+3y+3y+y$, right ?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade Not really. Anyway I fixed my post so there's not a mistake now.